# Assert exception with PHPUnit

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have a function to calculate the value of one square and i want to make the test of this.

The function squaring is this:

```
 public function squaring($number)
    {
        if ($number == 0) {
            throw new InvalidDataException("0 can't be squared");
        }

        return $number * $number;
    }
```

The first step of test it's check if it's correct:

```
  public function testIfSquaringIsCorrect()
    {
        $number = 2;

        $result = $this->modelPractice->squaring($number);

        $this->assertEquals(4, $result);
    }
```

And the last step check if I get the exception.

How can I do it?

I try it like this but it's not working:

```
  public function testSquaringLaunchInvalidDataException()
{
    $number = 0;

    $result = $this->modelPractice->squaring($number);

    $expected = $this->exceptException(InvalidDataException::class);

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Read the docs on [testing exceptions](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions)

Comment: You misspelled the name of [`expectException()`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions). And it must be invoked **before** running the code that throws the exception (*$this->modelPractice->squaring($number);*). After it, it doesn't even run because the tested code has already thrown an exception and nobody caught it.

Answer (score 8):

Phpunit has dedicated exception assertions:

```
$this->expectException(InvalidArgumentException::class);
```

See: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions

Comment: I read it before post the question, I think I understand it but now I need to compare the expected exception with what I get. I update the question with my code, know what's wrong? @FMK

Comment: From the link in my post: `In addition to the expectException() method the expectExceptionCode(), expectExceptionMessage(), and expectExceptionMessageRegExp() methods exist to set up expectations for exceptions raised by the code under test.` With this you can access all information from the exception! This should solve your problem!?

Comment: I'd advise against checking exception message values, as a rule they should be intended for the user (or at least developer) to read.  Fixing a spelling mistake or localising for a different language should not cause a test to fail!  Checking the exception class and code should be fine for unit tests (and it's definitely an idea to make your own custom exceptions to identify various classes of errors)